# NSPredicate that returns common list from 2 Core Data NSManagedObjects

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

Lets say I have 3 `NSManagedObjects` in Core Data called "Boys", "Girls", and "Hats".  "Hats" has a many-to-many relationship with both "Boys" and "Girls".  So each girl can have many "Hats", and each hat can have many "Girls", same with boys.

[image]

Using a `NSPredicate`, how can I find a common list of "Hats" that Boy A and Girl 1 have a relationship?

So, I want a to retrieve all the "Hats" that both John and Sally can wear. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY boys.name = %@ AND ANY girls.name = %@",
    @"John", @"Sally"]
```

should do the trick.